# On $(\mathcal C[0,1],||\cdot||_\infty)$, where $(Kf)(x):=\int k(x,y)f(y)dy$, what is $||K||$?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

This question is part of a prelim exam in analysis I'm taking to prepare for my own prelim. I have already proven $K$ is bounded and linear, for an earlier part of the problem.

We are given that $k:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is a fixed, continuous function, and $K: \mathcal C[0,1]\to\mathcal C[0,1]$.

The prompt actually suggests that $$\lVert K \rVert = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 |k(x,y)|dy$$
and we are asked to prove this. I can show (I think) that the norm is less than or equal to the above, but I cannot seem to show equality. I have tried to come up with an example in which $$\lVert (Kf)(x) \rVert = \lVert f \rVert_\infty \cdot \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 |k(x,y)|dy$$
But I can't do so. My best idea now is to find a sequence of functions $f_n$ that come arbitrarily close to the above equality, but I haven't succeeded there either. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hypotheses on $K$?

Comment: @zhw Sorry, I've edited to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas: Find $x_0$ such that $\int_0^1 |k(x_0,y)|\,dy$ is a maximum. There is a sequence $f_n$ in $C[0,1]$ that converge pointwise a.e. to $\text { sgn }[k(x_0,y)],$ with $|f_n|\le 1$ for every $n.$ By the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\int_0^1 |k(x_0,y)|\,dy = \int_0^1 k(x_0,y)\text { sgn }[k(x_0,y)]\,dy =\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 k(x_0,y)f_n(y)\,dy.$$

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your second sentence? I don't know why we can find such a sequence $(f_n)$, and with norm $\le 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Every bounded measurable function $f$ is the a.e. limit of continuous functions that are bounded in $\sup$-norm by the $L^\infty$ norm of $f.$ This is a consequence of Lusin's theorem. Here, however, the situation is more elementary. All we need to do is find continuous functions that converge pointwise everywhere to $\chi_U,$ where $U$ is open, with appropriate bounds on the continuous functions. This is a nice exercise if you haven't yet done it.

Comment: OK. I can find $f_n(x) = \max \{ 1 - n \cdot \text{dist}(x,U),0\}$ is continuous and $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise a.e. to $\chi_U$. But how does this tie in to a sign function?

Comment: Think about the sign function for a continuous function. It's 1 on an open set, -1 on on an open set, 0 everywhere else.

Comment: Alright I think I've got it. Let $f$ be continuous. Then sign$(f)$ is 1 on some open set $U_1$ and $-1$ on some open set $U_{-1}$ and zero elsewhere. so I could find continuous $f_n(x)$ converging pointwise to $\chi_{U_1}$ and continuous $g_n(x)$ converging pointwise to $-\chi_{U_{-1}}$, and then their sum is continuous and converges pointwise to the sign of $f$.

Comment: That's right, and the sup norms are bounded by 1. In fact this problem could be done  with just the Riemann theory I think